# Excel: How to add unique values based on another column but not unique when on its own

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, office365, uniqueidentifier

Is there way to achieve the `SUM()` of all the *unique* values in the `WEIGHT` column, based on the unique value from `VISIT ID` column, and only add those that repeat only if the `VISIT ID` value changes?

So control-break on `VISIT ID` and add **unique** values per `VISIT ID`. I hope that made sense? Thanks

*The `SUM()` here is only for illustration of what I am trying to achieve.*

[image]

Data:

```
VISIT ID    VESSEL NAME  WEIGHT 
15  FLORA DELMAS     2,740.9580 
15  FLORA DELMAS     2,740.9580 
15  FLORA DELMAS     2,740.9580 
15  FLORA DELMAS     2,740.9580 
15  FLORA DELMAS     2,591.1002 
15  FLORA DELMAS     2,591.1002 
15  FLORA DELMAS     2,591.1002 
15  FLORA DELMAS     578.7480 
15  FLORA DELMAS     124.9010 
15  FLORA DELMAS     19,994.0000 
20  SOUTHGATE    19,994.0000 
20  SOUTHGATE    19,994.0000 
20  SOUTHGATE    11,013.0000 
22  CAMILA   11,013.0000 
22  CAMILA   28,521.0000 
32  GULF LIVESTOCK 1     3,696.0000 
32  GULF LIVESTOCK 1     3,696.0000 
34  GOLDEN YOSA  2,905.0000
```

**UPDATE 1**

I forgot to say that I want the formula to use the range by columns and not across several *adjacent* columns... ie: A2:A19 **and** C2:C19... as the unique identifiers. Reason is I have many columns actually between A and C that are not in this sample, and I don't want to span all of them as they could change for other reasons.

Comment: What is your excel version? Post data as text so that we can copy.

Comment: Excel 365 - latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `F1`:

```
=SUM(INDEX(UNIQUE(A2:C19,0),0,3))
```

Or, specifically `VISIT ID` and `WEIGHT`:

```
=SUM(INDEX(UNIQUE(CHOOSE({1,2},A2:A19,C2:C19)),0,2))
=SUM(TAKE(UNIQUE(HSTACK(A2:A19,C2:C19)),,-1))
```

Comment: Thanks. Ok I'll have to study what's going on here.

Comment: I've updated my OP

Comment: @Fandango68, right. Updated.

Comment: Thanks again. The 2nd HSTACK() version. What is that? I get #NAME error. Also could you please breakdown why the 1st one worked, specifically the {1,2}? I've never seen formulas like this. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Give a try on-

```
=SUM(FILTER(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:C19,{1,0,1})),{0,1}))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to say that I want the formula to use the range by columns and not across several adjacent columns... ie: A2:A19 and C2:C19... reason is I have many columns between A and C that are not in this sample, and I don't want to span all of them as they could change for other reasons.

Comment: @Fandango68 The use `=SUM(INDEX(UNIQUE(CHOOSE({1,2},A2:A19,C2:C19)),,2))` or without index `=SUM(FILTER(UNIQUE(CHOOSE({1,2},A2:A19,C2:C19)),{0,1}))`.